# How to create checklist in Configuration from VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I create a checklist in configuration panel via extension.

I dont see an option to do this in documentation. Something like this:

[image]

Tried placing it hierarchically but UI seems to be different :

```
    "apexPMD.rulefix.1": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "If Else Statements Must use Braces"
    },
    "apexPMD.rulefix.2": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "For Statements Must use Braces"
    },
    "apexPMD.rulefix.3": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "While Statements Must use Braces"
    },
```

[image]

Comment: add individual boolean settings, choose the name hierarchical so they are placed together in the GUI

Comment: @rioV8 I understood the boolean part, but didnt understand the hierarchical part

Comment: I tried hierarchical approach but it seems to be not showing as expected.

Comment: if you name them alphabetically they might end up in a weird order. Don't name them with numbers (rule.1, rule.2) but with names (rule.for, rule.else). How does the Settings for other linters look like. If it is different take a look at there `package.json`

Comment: CSS/LESS and Python linters all use separate booleans and choice boxes

Comment: Same for all, separate choice boxes. Also even if I name then with names, they look the same as above.